# R - transform scaled and centered data to original values

Tags: r

If I scale and centre numeric column in a data frame (each value in each column divided by respective column SD and the mean of each respective column subtracted from each value) - how do I then back-transform to original values.

In the simple example below I see that the mean and SD of each column are stored in the object d4 after application of  'scale' with centering.

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(seq(1,20,1))
d2 <- as.data.frame(seq(0.11,0.3,0.01))
d3 <- cbind(d1,d2)
names(d3) <- c("A","B")
d4 <- scale(d3,center=TRUE)
d4

                A           B
 [1,] -1.60579308 -1.60579308
 [2,] -1.43676223 -1.43676223
 [3,] -1.26773138 -1.26773138
 [4,] -1.09870053 -1.09870053
 [5,] -0.92966968 -0.92966968
 [6,] -0.76063883 -0.76063883
 [7,] -0.59160798 -0.59160798
 [8,] -0.42257713 -0.42257713
 [9,] -0.25354628 -0.25354628
[10,] -0.08451543 -0.08451543
[11,]  0.08451543  0.08451543
[12,]  0.25354628  0.25354628
[13,]  0.42257713  0.42257713
[14,]  0.59160798  0.59160798
[15,]  0.76063883  0.76063883
[16,]  0.92966968  0.92966968
[17,]  1.09870053  1.09870053
[18,]  1.26773138  1.26773138
[19,]  1.43676223  1.43676223
[20,]  1.60579308  1.60579308
attr(,"scaled:center")
     A      B 
10.500  0.205 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
        A         B 
5.9160798 0.0591608
```

How can I now use the stored mean and SD values to compute from d4 the data frame of original values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
r1 <- d4 * attr(d4, 'scaled:scale')[col(d4)] + attr(d4, 'scaled:center')[col(d4)]
all.equal(as.data.frame(r1), d3)
#[1] TRUE
```